# JS Timer Trigger the counter in two tabs

Tags: javascript, tabs, settimeout

Is there a reason for window.setTimeOut() trigger the event in two tabs or navigators at same time?

I created a countdown timmer that is triggered when a method is called. But, if I open two tabs and call the function that trigger the timer in one tab, then open a second tab and trigger that event again, the counter in first tab is refreshed too.

My application runs in nodejs, but my functions are in client js files.

Comment: Can you provide some code to demonstrate the problem?

Comment: How are the two tabs connected?

Answer (score 0):

I just realized why it was working into two or more tabs/navigators. It was because I didn't have knowledge that, node was broadcasting the function that I was using too.

@Matt I am working in a node.js project. Then I found the function I am using being broadcasted into node.js to all the other clients.

@Bergi, they are connected using node.js.

I just removed the function from there and it worked just fine.